# Send one-liners from vim to R

Tags: command-line

As the title said, I would like to select and send to execute lines from my vim script to the statistical software package R (say an instance of it open in a different terminal).

While there is a maintained plugin (N-vim) that allows to do what I am looking for, it also provides a lot more clutter which I don't want/need.

Is there away to achieve that one functionality? I am running Arch Linux on a headless server.

Comment: have you tried something like: `:!R` ? You can pass to an external program lines from your buffer. e.g. in visual mode with a selection: `:'<,'>!ls`

Comment: @Nobe4 I am afraid that might not work, as I need to pass it to the current instance. Plugins like n-vim I believe rely on simulating some sort of TCP server to communicate between the two software. But I do not know enough to work that out. I shall try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this plugin just released for interfacing vim and interpreters like R or python:

https://github.com/iago-lito/intim/

It provides a few more features than you'd actually expect, but you sure can send one-liners with the only mapping:

```
nmap <space> <Plug>IntimSendLine
```

Try it out, and don't hesitate to file your first bug reports / feature requests on the repo :)